# How to calibrate/put points on a network

Tags: network-analyst, linear-referencing

I would like to staled points on a network. I have shape-point and I would like to take them and put/position  them to position correctly on the network.

I think it's easy but I'm lost[image]

Comment: What does `staled` mean?  Are you using ArcGIS Network Analyst or something else?

Comment: it mean move or stretch. I am using linear referencing tools

Comment: Do you perhaps mean `scaled`?  I've done a reasonable amount with linear referencing over the years, and have never come across `staled` in that or any other context.

Comment: As you specifically mention linear referencing sounds like you want to be using the "Locate Features Along Routes (Linear Referencing)" tool?

Comment: @PolyGeo, I want to Move/stall the point on/above the line.

Comment: @Hornbydd. I used the tool : locate feature Along Routes, the result is a table and when i make display XY , the position of the points is the same as the input feature. The points have not moved!!!

Comment: After running the tool you get a table, which will have MEASURE along the ROUTE, any XY fields in your original dataset are irrelevant. You would visualize the points on your route by right clicking on your table in the TOC and choosing DISPLAY ROUTE EVENTS, not display XY data.